# What is the meaning of "on the edge"

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

What is the meaning of **on the edge** in following sentence:

> His openness and celebration of sexuality, and not just heterosexual
>   sex, but sex **on the edges**-- masturbation, voyeurism, oral sex.

Comment: On the edges of society, or on the edges of what is considered "normal''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edge** figurative use [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59504?redirectedFrom=on%20the%20edge#eid5733107)

> b. A perilous path on a narrow ridge; figurative a sharp dividing
>   line; a critical position or moment.

As in:

His openness and celebration of sexuality, and not just heterosexual sex, but sex on the edges (*a dividing line*)-- masturbation, voyeurism, oral sex.